# Is there any way to have a diode that have very small resistance from reverse path?

Tags: resistors, diodes, negative-voltage, diode-clamp

I'm trying to find a way so I will always have close to `0V` at the measurement point (above the diode), when I have `0V` as input. The `-3.3V` is a fixed voltage source.

At `0.64V` at input, I have `-5.7mV` at the measurement point. That's OK to me.
At `3.3V` at input, I have `2.2V` at the measurement point. That's OK to me.

But when I have `0V` at input, then I have `-271.2mV` at the measurement point. That's to much negative!

If the diode have at least 10 Ohm in resistance, then the measurement point would be very close to zero. I what it to happen. But I cannot use a diode. Is there any better way to solve this issue without using a diode, or using a better diode?

[image]

Update:

Try this with a 3.6V zener diode. Change the current source from 4-20mA and look at the output. At 4mA, then we have close to zero volt. At 20mA, then we have about 2.2V. OK! But at 0mA, then we have -225mV. That's not OK! It should be low as zero volt as well.

[image]

**Update:**

Here is my solution. Is it good? At 4mA, we have some voltage for the ADC and therefore, we can see that there is a sensor connected.

[image]

Comment: What is that circuit supposed to do?  Maybe there's a better way to reach your goal.

Comment: hm, why are expecting the voltgae across that voltage divider to ever be exactly 0 V here? As JRE says, what's the idea behind this?

Comment: @JRE I want to measure 4-20mA over a 160 Ohm resistor but the problem is that when I have 4mA over 160 Ohm resistor, then my ADC is reading 0.64V. I want to turn it down so when I have 4mA, I got 0.64V, which becomes later about 5mV. My ADC reference is variable, but fixed to ground.

Comment: I don't understand – what does a current sense thing have to do with this circuit? Also, if you want a different voltage from a particular current, why not simply use a different resistor?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson:  There's a schematic editor built into the site.  You can use it to draw a more complete schematic.

Comment: Hold on! I write a complete schematic. 5 min!

Comment: Done! Took me 4 min!

Comment: The OP is trying to get full-scale ADC range on a 4 - 20 mA input. This has been the subject of two previous questions. In one the OP has been challenged to do the calculations for accuracy on 20% - 100% range usage versus errors introduced by scaling and offset. There is no sign of these calculations yet.

Comment: @Transistor Your answer from that question is right, that's why I'm accepting it. The problem is that I'm using a microcontroller that have not the option to change the minus reference. Only positive reference. So I need to find a way to clamp negative voltage.

Comment: You don't have a negative voltage on the input so you don't need a clamp. You have an offset that you are trying to remove.

Comment: @Transistor Yes. I want to remove that. I don't have negative voltage at the input. Only -3.3V.

Comment: Clarification: you don't have a negative ADC input as long as your sensor is connected and powered. If your signal < 4 mA then you will need a clamp to protect against negative input to the ADC.

Comment: @Transistor Yes. I need to protect it. That's what I want. But this diode creates bout -271mV when I have 0mA as input.

Comment: _"this diode creates bout -271mV when I have 0mA as input."_ - and that is a problem because???

Comment: @BruceAbbott Because I have -3.3V that sucks voltage from the ground and by pass the diode.

Comment: So check the datasheet and see what it says that the input can tolerate below ground. It's usually something like -0.3 V.

Comment: _"But I cannot use a diode"_ - why can you not use a diode?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Because I want close to zero voltage, but when I'm using the diode, then -271mV appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ8MHa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. 4 - 20 mA to 0 - 3.3 V conversion.*

- Input span: \$5 - 1 = 4\ \mathrm V\$.
- Output span: \$ 3.3 - 0  = 3.3 \ \mathrm V \$.
- Attenuation: \$ \frac {3.3}4 \$ so let's set R3 = 330 kΩ and that makes R2 = 70 kΩ.
- Now fix the offset. The negative voltage has to be low enough that the \$ \frac {3.3}4 \$ divider pulls 1 V to 0 V. That means that
  \$ (1 + V_1)\frac {3.3}4  - V_1  = 0 \$
  so
  \$ 0.175 V_1 = 0.825 \$ and
  \$ V_1 = 4.71428 \ \mathrm V \$ (since you need such precision).
- Note that R2 and R3 are loading R1 and introducing an error which you will need to correct.
- You now have the problem of generating a precision -4.7142 V source.
- D1 will only conduct when the input current drops below 4 mA but there may be some reverse leakage current in normal operation so you will need to check the datasheets for that.

By now it should be clear to you why a direct 20% to 100% conversion of the 4 - 20 mA signal just using a 165 Ω resistor is such a good idea. All this complexity is going to add to your calibration nightmare.

You can check the errors by running the simulation on Figure 1 and hover over the various points on the schematic for various values of I1.

Comment: Yes, I understand that is very much complex. But I have an idea. If I remove the regular diode and change the zener to a 2.7V zener and make sure that it has a very low forward voltage. Then I will be able to get about -100mA for the ADC. And the ADC have -300mA limit.

Comment: Have a look at my solution in the updated question. What do you think?

Comment: Ok. I think I will give up. It's much better to accept 20% lose, than working with external complexity. But how do they doing in real industrial applications?

Comment: I told you the answer to that two questions ago. Read it again - it may be in the comments.

Comment: "*Have a look at my solution in the updated question. What do you think?*" It looks a mess. There is no good reason for a Zener (note capital for the guy's name) diode.

Comment: Thank you. I think your opinion for 20% lose conversion is a good answer.